# Is it possible to repurpose old Bluetooth remotes into Bluetooth dongles?

Tags: bluetooth, dongle

I have picked up a cheap Bluetooth remote shutter (AB Shutter 3) from a shop. On the PCB it turns out that the firmware chip code is

```
ATHYC802
24C02N
SU27 D
```

and the (supposedly) Bluetooth chip code is

```
YC1089
E8R068
1841A6
```

I was wondering if it was possible to modify the PCB in such a way that a USB Male connector could be attached to the Bluetooth chip on the PCB so that i can connect it to my computer in order to have Bluetooth connectivity on my computer. Is it possible to do this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

## This is not possible.

Bluetooth devices are either master (computers, phones, etc) or slave (speakers, mouse, etc). While both devices have the ability to receive and transmit, only master devices have the hardware needed to pair connections.

If you want to add Bluetooth to your computer, there are a wide variety of off-the-shelf Bluetooth adapters to purchase.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What does make a master device a master device? Does the hardware differ from slave devices, or is it a firmware thing?

Comment: @dirdi Essentially Both.  While it is entirely *possible* to make a device do both, thats not how they are made or designed.